# Graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2+1$ edges has at least $n$ triangles.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I have the following graph theory problem.

> **Problem.** Let $n>1$ be an integer.  Given a simple graph $G=(V, E)$ with $|V|=2n$ and $|E|=n^2+1$. Prove that there at least $n$ triangles in the graph $G$.

Clearly, from Turan's theorem we obtain that there is at least one triangle in $G$, but it isn't sufficient to solve the problem.
For some small $n$ it can be proved by casework. It is also clear that the bound is sharp. Namely, in graph $K_{n,n}$ with one additional edge there are exactly $n$ triangles.

How can we approach this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Show by induction a more general result:

> Given a graph $G=(V, E)$ with $|V|=2n+x$ with $x\in\{0,1\}$ and $|E|=n(n + x) + 1$. Prove that there are at least $n$ triangles in $G$.

Note that in $G$ there is a vertex of degree $\leq n$, otherwise
$$(n+1)(2n+x)=(n+1)|V|\leq\sum_{v\in V}\text{deg}(v)=2|E|=2n(n + x) + 2$$
which implies that $0>(x-2)(n-1)\geq 0$. Contradiction.

Now, remove such vertex $v$ and apply the induction hypothesis to the graph $G\setminus \{v\}$.

Comment: How are you applying the induction hypothesis?

Comment: Robert Z, how will we find additional triangle after applying the induction hypothesis?

Comment: @richrow I neat description of how to apply induction hypothesis is given here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/698911/299698